# Get a range of days in Python

Tags: python

I'm making a schedule app and I need a way to categorize range of days for each block. The days are marked as integers:

`MON, TUE, WEN, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN` is `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`

So let's say I've scheduled a block that starts Tuesday and ends Friday.
Identifying its range is easy:

`range(block.start_day, block.end_day +1)` would give me `(1, 4)`.

But that won't work if a block starts Saturday and ends Wednesday.

The result I need is `(5, 6, 0, 1, 2)`.

I'm kinda stuck at this part. I guess I could use a modulo operator, but I'm not sure.

** EDIT **
I apologize, I've updated the correct desired output.

Using Python 2.7.6

Comment: Can a range be longer than a week?  If so, how do you anticipate handling that?

Comment: @ScottHunter no, range cannot be longer than a week.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3? Range is a list in 2, but an iterator in 3, and that might affect your solution.

Comment: Have you considered using pandas http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html ?

Comment: I think it can be done elegantly with `itertools.cycle` and `itertools.islice`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def days(f, L):
    if f > L:
        x = list(range(0, 7))
        return x[f:] + x[:L+1]
    else:
        return list(range(f, L+1))
```

`days(5, 3)` returns `[5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3]`

`days(3, 5)` returns `[3, 4, 5]`

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is use conditional logic:

```
def get_range(start_day, end_day):
    if (start_day < end_day):
        r = range(start_day, end_day + 1)
    else:
        r1 = range(start_day, 7)
        r2 = range(0, end_day + 1)
        r = r1 + r2
    return r
```

I'm sure someone on here can come up with a more elegant solution, but this gets you started.

Just for the sake of thoroughness, I believe the same thing can be accomplished in python 3 (where range produces an iterator, rather than a list) using `itertools.chain` instead of `+` to concatenate `r1` and `r2`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to deal with odd ranges is to implement a custom range function:

```
def date_range(start, end):
    'Return a list of weekday values in the range [START, END]'
    names = dict(zip(
        ['MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT', 'SUN'],
        range(7)))
    try:
        start = names[start.upper()]
    except:
        pass
    try:
        end = names[end.upper()]
    except:
        pass
    while True:
        yield start % 7
        if start % 7 == end % 7:
            return
        start += 1

print list(date_range('tue', 'fri'))
print list(date_range('sat', 'wed'))
print list(date_range(5, 2))
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 0, 1, 2]
[5, 6, 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
def get_range(f):
    week = list(range(7))
    if f[1] < f[0]:
        _curr = week[f[0]:]
        _rest = week[:f[1]+1]
        return _curr+_rest
    else:
        return range(f[0],f[1]+1)
```

result:

```
get_range([1,4]) -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
get_range([5,2]) -> [5, 6, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: What does `get_range([4,1])` produce? Also, `x` is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
def getrange(start,end):
    result = [start]
    week = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    c = start
    while (week[c%7] != end):
        c = c + 1
        result.append(week[c%7])
    return result
```

**Testcases:**

```
getrange(1,4) =>[1,2,3,4]
getrange(5,2) =>[5,6,0,1,2]
```